# How can I render different data from a single react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display `mychart1` on home page and `mychart2` on contact page. I have created 2 charts i.e `mychart1` and `mychart2`. Now how can I separate two charts so that on home page `mychart1` is displayed and on contact page `mychart2` is displayed.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Barchart extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    const data1 = {
        labels: ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL'],
        series: [20, 60, 120, 200, 180, 20, 10]
    }

    const options1 = {
        width:300,
        height:300,
        distributeSeries: true
    }

    const mychart1 = new Chartist.Bar('.ct-bar-chart', data1,options1);

    const data2 = {
        labels: ['A', 'S', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
        series: [120, 160, 120, 200, 180, 120, 110]
    }

    const options2 = {
        width:300,
        height:300,
        distributeSeries: true
    }

    const mychart2 = new Chartist.Bar('.ct-bar-chart', data2,options2);

  }


  render(){
    return(
         <div className="ct-bar-chart">
             {this.mychart1}
             {this.mychart2}
         </div>

    )}
}

export default Barchart ;
```

Example:

In home component:

```
<Barchart mydata1={this.props.batdata}/>
```

In information component:

```
<Barchart mydata2={this.props.bowldata}/>
```

Comment: Just include the <BarChart /> inside your home page and your contact page component ? If you want to have different data, it'll have to be with props or some sort of service observable which the chart will subscribe to.

Comment: Are you using react router?

Comment: @Colin No I am not using react router

Comment: Okay well then as @JonathanHamel mentioned, this seems simple enough – can you show more code or explain more what you want to do?

Comment: @JonathanHamel Check my updated code.

Comment: @Colin  Check my updated code.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, because the BarChart component will always just render `this.mychart1` the way you have it?

Comment: @Colin Can I make separate functions and render them is it possible ?

Comment: You should consider using a react charting library:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2 see their documentation, pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2 (A react charting library instead of a library that will manipulate the DOM while react also tries to manipulate it).

You will then be able to use a single component in you `home` and `contact` component.

```
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

In your render function, you can add these

```
<Bar
    data={data}
    width={100}
    height={50}
    options={{
        maintainAspectRatio: false
    }}
/>
```

If you want to stick with your version, you'll have to use a ID selector (passed as props from your `home` or `contact` page) instead of a class selector in this line. Also, passing your data and options as props would be the best option here.

```
const mychart = new Chartist.Bar(this.props.selector, this.props.data, this.props.options);
```

Comment: If you (OP) are willing to reconsider your overall approach, this is a good long-term solution that will be more likely to prevent problems in the future and is more modular in case you need other charts later.

Answer (score -1):

Updated example to show use of React Router for displaying different pages (components), and thus different bar charts. Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/734kx5rnzj).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const PageOne = () => {
  const data = "Data One";
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <BarChart data={data} />
      <Link to="/two">Go to Two</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const PageTwo = () => {
  const data = "Data Two";

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <BarChart data={data} />
      <Link to="/one">Go to One</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  return <Link to="/one">Go to page one</Link>;
};

const BarChart = ({ data }) => {
  return <h1>BarChart of {data}</h1>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/one" component={PageOne} />
        <Route path="/two" component={PageTwo} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I want to display pie chart with different data on different pages. Your example displays both charts on single page

Comment: OP didn't ask how to pass data as props and is already doing so in the example. The question, rather, is how to display only the desired chart.

Comment: @223seneca OP's original question seems to display some fundamental misunderstandings, and so while OP is passing props, they are doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes so I can improve my answer?